# Grafana for user authenticated data visualization

Tags: html, time-series, visualization, grafana

I’ve used Grafana many times before to show dashboard data to a Sysadmin.
I like Grafana because it is very easy to use and shows nice looking graphs by default.

However, now I want to create a user facing screen which shows a specific user’s data based on a user login. This means that the query result should be authenticated, and shown only to that specific user.
For example: The balance in a bank account over time.

Unlike a system dashboard which has access to everything, a specific user can only see their specific stats.

Is there any way I can use a shared Grafana instance to display this kind of personal data?

Is there another tool that can do this?

Or do I need to go with a low level approach like: Google Charts coupled with my own backend service to handle the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: it depends on used datasource and implementation. Some Grafana datasources support `Forward OAuth Identity` feature:

> Forward the user's upstream OAuth identity to the datasource (Their access token gets passed along).

[image]

So datasource may use this forwarded user identity to build proper customized response. It is OAuth access token, so identity can be verified and faked identity can be denied.

Comment: I still have an option to change my datasource, do you have a recomendation? (currently using influxDB)

Comment: What I known, there is no real timeseries DB, which is able to use it. So you will need to code it - some additional layer on top of existing timeseries DB.